# Material UI - Vertically Stack Typography and CircularProgress within Backdrop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I stack a `CircularProgress` component on top of a `Typography` component (both of which are in a `Backdrop` component)?

Currently, the progress component is on the left and the text is right next to the progress bar. I've attempted to use grid items/containers but no luck so far.

[image]

```
<Backdrop open={loading} style={{zIndex: 20, opacity: 0.8, backgroundColor: '#FFFF', color: '#0000'}}>
   <Grid container alignItems='center' justify='center' alignContent='center'>
       <Grid item sm={12} md={12} lg={12} align='center'>
           <PurpleProgress/>
       </Grid>
       <Grid item sm={12} md={12} lg={12} align='center'>
           <Typography variant="body2" style={{color: '#000000'}}><b>{message}</b></Typography>
       </Grid>
   </Grid>
</Backdrop>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably having this issue on small screens because you do not have the `xs` prop set to take up the entire grid. To solve this issue, if you want the stacking to be consistent across all screen sizes, you can just use `xs={12}`

```
<Grid container alignItems='center' justify='center' alignContent='center'>
    <Grid item xs={12} align='center'>
        <PurpleProgress/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} align='center'>
        <Typography variant="body2" style={{color: '#000000'}}><b>{message}</b></Typography>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Comment: Thanks that did the trick! So dang simple and I completely overlooked it. I appreciate the help